# How to use string variable in a for loop container?

Tags: ssis

I have the for loop task that will download a file from source file and upload in sql file. I have a variable in SSIS which will contain if a certain column is Y or N. My question is how can I use the variable in my for loop container?  The logic is my ssis will download and upload the file until the certain column is set to Y. Here is my toolbox inside the container.

SQL Task(Truncate table)-Download the file-->Upload the file in sql table-->SQL Task(that will query if the column is Y or N and pass it to the variable)

I need to loop the toolbox above until I get the Y in the column.

Comment: What do I need to put in the initexpression,evalexpression and assignexpression. Thanks!

Comment: Use it in the EvalExpression

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess based on what you said in your broken explanation above:

You are file that you are pulling down that has a column with a possible value of Y or N. In your initial pull you just want to pull the file down and load it to a table. Then you will go read the value in the table for that column and assign that value to a variable. Then, based on the variable value you want to re-loop to get the next file or the same one?

But, from what I understood:

Lets say your variable name is called `CheckFlag`, set it to string and value it N or Y, don't matter because you will be re-setting the value of the variable inside the loop using your Execute SQL Task anyway.

`initExpression: @CheckFlag == @CheckFlag` (true, lets start the loop)

`evalExpression: @CheckFlag == "Y"` (loop until the variable value is Y)

No need to use the `assignExpression` because you are assigning the value to your variable using the Execute SQL Task already.